# How to remove single quotes from string in TypeScript

Tags: string, typescript

I want to remove single quote from the string in TypeScript. I have used the following ways to achieve that.

```
var Id = this.currentId.replaceAll('"','');
var id = this.currentId.remove('\'', '');
```

tried the above methods.

thanks in Advance

Comment: you need to write a regex for this. use this regex to replace single quotes (/'/g, "")

Comment: @VikasSingh Can you pls show one example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to find and remove all single quotes in a string.

Example:

```
const stringWithoutSingleQuotes = stringWithSingleQuoutes.replace(/'/g, "")
```

Comment: thanks, its working, but I want to replace all the single quotes in a string and 'replaceAll' is not available in typescript. is there any other way to replace all the single quotes.

Comment: `replace()` is available in TypeScript, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20stringWithSingleQuotes%20%3D%20%22'a'b'c'd'e'f'g'%22%0D%0Aconst%20stringWithoutSingleQuotes%20%3D%20stringWithSingleQuotes.replace(%2F'%2Fg%2C%20%22%22)%0D%0Aconsole.log(stringWithoutSingleQuotes) for a working example.